Inserting an XML string in existing document with C# breaks everything
I'm using C# with the System.Xml classes to manipulate an existing XML document.
In particular, I need to insert pieces of XML that I have in string form inside specific nodes in the document.
To do this, I create a new element and then set my XML string in its InnerXml property, like this:
using System.Xml;

string nsUri = "http://myorg/myns";
string baseDocument = @$"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-16""?><Root xmlns=""{nsUri}""></Root>";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(baseDocument);
var nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsm.AddNamespace("default", nsUri);

var target = doc.CreateElement("Target", nsUri);
target.InnerXml= @"
    <Sub1>This is a subnode</Sub1>
    <Sub2>Here is another subnode</Sub2>
";
doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(target);

doc.Save(@"C:\text.xml");

Looking at the output, here's the result:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Root xmlns="http://myorg/myns">
  <Target>
    <Sub1 xmlns="">This is a subnode</Sub1>
    <Sub2 xmlns="">Here is another subnode</Sub2>
</Target>
</Root>

As you can see, there's an issue: every sub-node inside the XML string I inserted gets assigned an empty xmlns attribute: xmlns="".
This in itself is already a problem, but the far worse issue is that after doing this the document seems to be in an inconsistent state and further manipulation produces weird results. For example, if after doing this I do:
var sub1 = target.SelectSingleNode("default:Sub1", nsm);

then sub1 is null.
So, apparently this is not the correct way to do this, and the problem happens when I reassign InnerXml. Can you tell me the proper way to do this?
Some notes:

I know I can create the elements and attributes one by one instead of just dumping the XML string inside InnerXml, but the XML fragments I need to insert are very long and it would be absurd to manually recreate them in code.
I tried doing this with XmlDocumentFragment but the result is exactly the same


While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
Please edit your original question and provide the following:
(1) Well-formed XML file sample.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your code attempt trying to implement it.
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in #1 above.

It is better to use LINQ to XML API. It is available in the .Net Framework since 2007.

@YitzhakKhabinsky: did you read the question? The code I've provided IS a minimal reproducible example, it DOES contain the well-formed input XML and you can run it directly and it will produce the output I've shown. As for using LINQ to XML: can the two approaches be mixed? Because the existing codebase is quite large and it uses System.Xml everywhere, I cannot rewrite it entirely unfortunately, even if I wanted.

@user246821: those solutions don't seem to apply to my question... as I've said: I want to insert an entire (potentially very long) fragment of XML in the document, the solutions you linked create the single elements and attributes one-by-one, which would be insane in my use case

Unfortunately, what you're attempting to accomplish is unclear. You mentioned I need to insert pieces of XML that I have in string form inside specific nodes in the document. However, the code you provided doesn't demonstrate that. Where's the variable that contains the string data? If the variable contains the hard-coded values that you've added, without using a variable, why is this information in a string in the first place? Where did it come from?

Does How to change or inherit the default namespace when setting InnerXml answer your question?

Seems like the answer from How to change or inherit the default namespace when setting InnerXml does work: target.SetInnerXmlAndInheritDefaultNamespace(innerXml); produces the result you want, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/fIw5W6.

One note about SetInnerXmlAndInheritDefaultNamespace -- you need to append the target element to its parent before setting the inner XML.  If you don't you may get redundant namespace declarations.  Anyway, mark as a duplicate?

@dbc: +1, I ended up using the simpler solution that was suggested below, but I tested the answer you linked and it also works (the only drawback, as you said, is that it only works if the node you're injecting the XML into has already been appended to it's final parent node, so you must remember to always to it in that order)

XmlElement.InnerXml apparently considers an element without an explicit namespace as belonging to the empty namespace. Therefore, the best solution is to fix the problem at the source: Ensure that whatever generates your XML string specifies the correct namespace for every element. (Otherwise, out of context, it's unclear what namespace <Sub1> and <Sub2> belong to.)
However, if that's not feasible, and you're willing to assume that all elements without a namespace attribute in your XML string belong to a specified default namespace, then an alternative approach is to create a document fragment, set its InnerXml to your XML string in a context with the desired default namespace, and then append the fragment to the document:
// As before...
string nsUri = "http://myorg/myns";
string baseDocument = @$"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-16""?><Root xmlns=""{nsUri}""></Root>";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(baseDocument);
var nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsm.AddNamespace("default", nsUri);

// Create the <Target> element using CreateDocumentFragment instead of CreateElement:
var fragment = doc.CreateDocumentFragment();
fragment.InnerXml = @$"<Target xmlns=""{nsUri}"">
    <Sub1>This is a subnode</Sub1>
    <Sub2>Here is another subnode</Sub2>
  </Target>";
var node = doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(fragment);
node.Attributes.RemoveNamedItem("xmlns"); // Remove the redundant xmlns attribute on <Target>.

doc.Save(@"C:\text.xml");

Here's the result:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Root xmlns="http://myorg/myns">
  <Target>
    <Sub1>This is a subnode</Sub1>
    <Sub2>Here is another subnode</Sub2>
  </Target>
</Root>


This is the only solution that seems to work correctly for my use case, I didn't think to just remove the xmlns like it was just another random attribute but it makes sense since the root document already specifies a default namespace. Thanks!

I don't see a really simple way to mix the DOM and XML text like this (neither high-level API supports XML Fragments), but dropping down and using an XmlReader, you can get it done.  Also switching to XDocument, EG
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

XNamespace ns = "http://myorg/myns";
string baseDocument = @$"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-16""?><Root xmlns=""{ns.ToString()}""></Root>";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(baseDocument);

var target = new XElement(ns + "Target");

var fragment = @"
    <Sub1>This is a subnode</Sub1>
    <Sub2>Here is another subnode</Sub2>
";
var settings = new XmlReaderSettings() { ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment };
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(fragment), settings);

while (reader.Read())
{
    while (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element)
    {
        if (!reader.Read()) break;
    }
    if (reader.EOF) break;
    var sr = reader.ReadSubtree(); 
    XElement subNode = XElement.Load(sr);
    subNode.Name = ns + subNode.Name.LocalName;
    target.Add(subNode);
}
doc.Root.Add(target);
Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());


Here is another solution by using LINQ to XML.
c#
void Main()
{
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(@"<Root xmlns='http://myorg/myns'>
        </Root>");

    XElement fragment = XElement.Parse(@"<Target>
            <Sub1>This is a subnode</Sub1>
            <Sub2>Here is another subnode</Sub2>
        </Target>");
    xdoc.Root.Add(fragment);

    foreach (var node in xdoc.Descendants()
        .Where(x => x.Name.NamespaceName == ""))
    {
            // Inherit the parent namespace instead
            node.Name = node.Parent.Name.Namespace + node.Name.LocalName;
    }
    xdoc.Save(@"e:\temp.xml");
}

Output
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root xmlns="http://myorg/myns">
  <Target>
    <Sub1>This is a subnode</Sub1>
    <Sub2>Here is another subnode</Sub2>
  </Target>
</Root>


You were almost there. The only thing you should create subs nodes and append them to the target. Something like this.
using System.Xml;
    string nsUri = "http://myorg/myns";
    string baseDocument = @$"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-16""?><Root xmlns=""{nsUri}""></Root>";

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(baseDocument);
    var nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
    nsm.AddNamespace("default", nsUri);

    var target = doc.CreateElement("Target", nsUri);
    var sub =doc.CreateElement("Sub1", nsUri);
    sub.InnerXml = "This is a subnode";
    target.AppendChild(sub);
    sub = doc.CreateElement("Sub2", nsUri);
    sub.InnerXml = "Here is another subnode";
    target.AppendChild(sub);
    doc.DocumentElement?.AppendChild(target);

    Console.WriteLine(doc.OuterXml);

The code produces exactly what you want. You can access elements as well.
var subBak = target.SelectSingleNode("default:Sub1", nsm);

